# Hunspell does not propose an obvious correct form of a misspelled word

Tags: windows, emacs, hunspell

For the misspelled word "**perapring**" hunspell does not propose the correct spelling "**preparing**" and only proposes the following words:

```
persevering
pertaining
innerspring
preferring
preprint
wraparound
```

Is there a workaround that hunspell proposes "preparing", for example by modifying "**default.aff**" file? Any solution is welcomed.

Note: I am using "hunspell" through emacs.